# Transform to a matrix with last two columns null

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix
$$
    A=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
    3 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
    1 & 5 & 0 & 8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

> Is it possible to transform $A$ by elementary operations to a matrix with the last two columns null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **NOTE :** $\rho,\nu,n$ stand for rank, nullity and number of columns respectively.

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\5\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\8\end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$ forms a basis of $\zeta(A)$, the column space of $A$
$\Rightarrow\dim(\zeta(A))=\rho(A)=3$

Suppose it is possible to transform $A$ using elementary operations to a matrix with the last two columns null. 
Let $B$ be the resultant matrix. Then, $\nu(B)\ge2,n(B)=4$ and
$$
    B=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 0 \\
    \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 0 \\
    \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}.
$$

> **Theorem :** An elementary operation does not alter the rank of a matrix.

Using the above theorem, we can say that $\rho(B)=\rho(A)=3$.

> **Rank-nullity theorem :** For any matrix $A$ with $n$ columns, $\nu(A)=n-\rho(A)$.

Using the rank-nullity theorem, we compute $\nu(B)=n(B)-\rho(B)=4-3=1<2$.
This is a contradiction to the definition of $B$ (last two columns null $\Rightarrow\nu(B)\ge2$).
Hence, our assumption is wrong i.e. it is **not** possible to transform $A$ to a matrix with last 2 columns null using elementary operations.